# Setting the number of times a function called back to 1, after one set of simulation done

Tags: python, counter

Hi i have a python wrapper function which counts the number of times a function is called and based on  each count i am performing some actions which writes the content to a html file. Now is there a way to set the counter back to 1 after one iteration, so that when i start for second iteration I want the count of htmloverview() to start from beginning and not count from previous values.

```
  Decorator:

   def counter(func):
      @wraps(func)
      def tmp(*args, **kwargs):
        tmp.count += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
        tmp.count = 0
        return tmp

  @counter
  def htmloverview(fileouthtml,resultfile,file,identical,namesBothSub):
     r= htmloverview.count
     if(len(diff)==0):
        if(r==1):
          s = '\n'.join([message,message1,'<td>','0','</td>','</tr>'])
        else:
          s = '\n'.join(['<tr>','<td>',message1,'<td>','0','</td>','</tr>']) 
     fileouthtml.write(s)
     fileouthtml.write('\n')
```

I can run the simulator 'n' times and each time when i run, i want the counter of htmloverview to start from beginning and not count from previous iteration, is there a way to do it.

Comment: could you provide more description to the question? It seems like you want to use the variable `r` as a boolean instead of a count. or is your question 'htmloverview will be run in a for loop, and after which the counter needs to be reset' ?

Comment: Yes the htmloverview() will be running in a for loop, and after the loop is completed, the counter needs to be reset.

Answer (score 1):

A class seems to be a better fit here than a decorator.

```
class Simulation(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.count = 0
        self._func = func
    def reset_count(self):
        self.count = 0
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.count += 1
        return self._func(*args, **kwargs)

sim = Simulation(htmloverview)
for i in range(100): #first iteration
    sim.run(fileouthtml,resultfile,file,identical,namesBothSub)
print sim.count #ran 100 times
sim.reset()
```

you could do error handling and keep error count and have multiple instances of simulation each with it's own value of count

Answer (score 0):

(Would have put this in a comment if I could)

I'm a bit unsure what you are trying to achieve. Do you want your function to have one behavior the first time you call it and another for all other calls, until you reset the state? Then you could either pass the state variable as a boolean parameter:

```
def htmloverview(fileouthtml,resultfile,file,identical,namesBothSub, first_call) # True/False
```

or you could keep the state in a global variable:

```
htmloverview_count=0

def htmloverview(fileouthtml,resultfile,file,identical,namesBothSub):

    global htmloverview_count

    if htmloverview_count>0:
        <do something>

     htmloverview_count+=1
```

And reset the state from the calling context:

```
htmloverview_count=0
```

If you have lots of functions with similar behavior it might make sense to use a decorator. Please elaborate your question: would any of the above solve your problem?